# NVD3 Legend Color Guide Rendering Issue - No color appearing in color guide in tooltip within Internet Explorer / Chrome

Tags: html, css, nvd3.js

**Issue**

I have an nvd3 chart I am trying to render with colors on the tooltip legend-color-guide.

The colors show up fine on the selector below in Firefox for multiple charts.  On Internet Explorer and Chrome I see only a white fill on the tooltip of each of the series for each chart.

**Note**

Through inspection in Internet Explorer I see that there is a color applied in the code but no color is rendered.

[Demo Here](http://vrjab.comxa.com/dashboard/charts.htm)

**Question**

How can I display color for the tooltip legend-color-guide in IE and Chrome?

**Inspected Code From Internet Explorer**

```
  <div class="nvtooltip xy-tooltip nv-pointer-events-none" id="nvtooltip-41258" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; opacity: 0; transform: translate(398px, 155.51px) !important;">
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><strong class="x-value">Oct 07, 2015</strong></td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="legend-color-guide">
               <div style="background-color: red;"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="key">Total Action Items</td>
            <td class="value">152</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="legend-color-guide">
               <div style="background-color: rgb(85, 85, 221);"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="key">ECD Items</td>
            <td class="value">130</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="legend-color-guide">
               <div style="background-color: orange;"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="key">Original Due Items</td>
            <td class="value">122</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="legend-color-guide">
               <div style="background-color: green;"></div>
            </td>
            <td class="key">Closed Items</td>
            <td class="value">63</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

[image: tooltip]

**CSS Selector**

```
  .nvtooltip table td.legend-color-guide div
```

**Code Snippet from nv.min.css**

```
.nvtooltip table td.legend-color-guide div {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nvtooltip table td.legend-color-guide div {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

Comment: These divs look empty, are you sure they have a defined width/height in the CSS?

Comment: I modified the post to include the css from my original setup.  This code was already included in my application.

Comment: that is strange... is there anything blocking it? are there divs above it or something? any positioning that may cause the divs to disappear? a live version would be helpful

Comment: The graphs are generated from php but the front end Is in html/css/js so I can try to create a demo.  I can see the html code inspector clearly showing a color in IE and Chrome, just no rendered color in the browser.

Comment: can you check if the divs are indeed where they are supposed to be through the inspector? usually when you select their tag in the inspector you would see the box highlighted, see anything?

Comment: Even i didn't see color in firefox also. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ESQbh.png

Comment: And there is applied `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)` so, it will display white color in tooltip. As per your demo provided.

Comment: The color appears to be showing up in your provided image for Firefox as mentioned.  It is red in the little square.  That square is not colored in IE.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Where I am stuck is how to get colors to appear in those little squares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add/change following css will make your color working in IE.

```
td > div:not(.filterinput):not(.cell){
  -ms-overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Currently it is `-ms-overflow-y:scroll;`

Answer (score 0):

Empty div with no height will never be rendered, try adding this CSS

```
.nvtooltip table td.legend-color-guide div { height:100%; min-height:10px; }
```

Comment: Please see new demo link in my original post demonstrating the issue.